# Why does my code delete entire text file instead of line?

Tags: python, file, urllib2

I'm checking a large list of URLs (one URL per line) for http codes. If one gives code 302 I want to delete that line from the file but everything I've tried just deletes the whole file. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Had wrong code pasted, Sorry! Also I have f.write("  ") as I was trying different methods of deleting the line, since everything I've tried just deletes all the whole file.

At first I was writing them to a new file, but It was taking too long(roughly 20k urls) so I figured deleting from the current file would be quicker. Or should I just stick with writing to a new file instead?

```
import urllib2, urllib

class NoRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        infourl = urllib.addinfourl(fp, headers, req.get_full_url())
        infourl.status = code
        infourl.code = code
        return infourl
    http_error_300 = http_error_302
    http_error_301 = http_error_302
    http_error_303 = http_error_302
    http_error_307 = http_error_302

opener = urllib2.build_opener(NoRedirectHandler())
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'birthtime=568022401'))

with open('list.txt', 'w+') as f:
    sites = f.readlines()
    for url in sites:
        try:
            connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            position = f.tell()
            if connection.getcode() is 302:
               f.write(" ")
            print "pos:", position
            print connection.getcode()
            connection.close()
        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            print e.getcode()
```

Comment: Can you show an actual working example? Because in this code, when calling `f.write()`, `f` is already closed. And it was never opened for writing in the first place

Comment: What about writing into a different file than the one you have open for reading?

Comment: Sorry, The r is suposed to be w+, edited it.

Comment: Assuming that the `f` of `f.write` is a new file. "if one gives code 302 I want to delete that line from the file" Well, according to `if connection.getcode() == 302:` you only write lines that _do_ get a `302` return code. Try negating this condition.

Comment: You code does not what you want in many ways. Is it an indention error that the ```for``` block is not in the ```with block```? Because in this case ```f``` is closed when you want to write to it and should give an error. Furthermore you write you want to delete urls that respond with a 302. bur your code actually only writes urls to the file that DO respond with 302.

Comment: 20k is nothing. Load all in at once and write all at once.

Comment: So I'd be better off writing to new file is what you are saying? I tried writing all the URLS that didn't respond with 302 to a new file, but something it stopped running at around 6k lines, so I decided to change how I was doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with your code

1. Your file is closed as soon you leave the `with` section.
2. You are opening the file just for reading
3. It's bad practice to read the whole line into memory.

You should:

1. Open source file for read
2. Open target file for write
3. Iterate over source line by line and if OK write to target
4. Close both files
5. Delete source and rename target to the original source name

Something like:

```
with open('list.txt', 'r') as source, open('list-ok.txt', 'w') as target:
  for url in source:
    if do_something(url):
      target.write(url)
# Rename here "list-ok.txt" to "list.txt"
```

Comment: I'm going through roughly 20k links, I should read it all, then write it all again? Wouldn't that take a lot of extra time?

Comment: .readlines() does read all lines from file and at once - takes at least as much memory as file size (actually more). You have no option - you have to read and write back if you are removing lines (making file shorter). There is no way around unless you implement some sort of commenting. For example have a "+" or "-" sign at beginning of line - then you can write to the same file by just replacing this character.

Comment: Oh okay. Will keep that in mind, thank you. I'm not too worried about memory at the moment though, I'm trying to figure out why it changes the whole file, instead of just the line.

Comment: because you are rewriting the file. You better update your post with you current code if you want to get answer as obviously what you posted can not work as there is no opening for writing.

Comment: Actually I see you updated the code. But as it was said you are writing just fails not success

Comment: Ah yes, I see now thank you. Even after changing == to is it's still deleting all lines. Does it not know what line it is on, so it changes everything or something?

Comment: Check .tell() and .seek() methods of file object - see for example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Comment: I put .tell() in and updated my code, but the position never moves. I also commented out my if statement but it still print's the same position over and over

Comment: That's why I told you to check seek. Or read file line by line, not .readlines()

Comment: Oh okay! I understand now. I will try doing it line by line, Thank you so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

you read sites from from 'list.txt'. and the file handler f only has the read permission, not has write permission.
the code: f.write(url). where do you want to write?

Comment: I had posted an older version of the code, my apologies.